# How to easily log XML-RPC traffic?

Tags: logging, proxy, xml-rpc

In a linux server environment I have an XML-RPC client and server application running.

I would like to analyze the communication between them and for that reason would need some kind of logging of the XML-RPC packets/messages.

Is there a simple way, maybe setting up a proxy beteen them that can log? Or a packet sniffer?

EDIT: I find it difficult to use wireshark, because both client and server are on a remote linux server. A local linux headless solution would be easier, unless someone knows a simple way to sniff packets on a remote system with wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used wireshark, it was quite simple and did the job.